# Maximum of 2 numbers in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Comparing 2 numbers: define a predicate `great` that takes 3 parameters - the 2 
numbers that I want to compare them and the output variable that return the 
greatest number.

Ex.

```
?- great(X,3,5). 
X=5.
```

in Prolog language

Comment: Do you mean Prolog? Or is there some kind of "bro"-variant of Prolog named "brolog"? :-D

Comment: prolog sorry its my fault

Comment: @Sergey that's funny. :D

Comment: @user3527224 have you looked at any documentation at all? Go find a Prolog manual online for GNU Prolog or SWI Prolog and look at the comparison operators. Then think of your predicate `great(X,Y,Z) :- ...` as meaning *`X` is the greater of `Y` and `Z` if...*. You can have more than one clause for the predicate. So to make it simple, you could have two: `great(Y, Y, Z) :-...` which is *`Y` is the greater of `Y` and `Z` if...* and `great(Z, Y, Z).` which is *`Z` is the greater of `Y` and `Z` if...*.

Answer (score 1):

You really should [read the documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=arith). Maybe even read a [good book on the language](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/art-prolog):

- `</2` is "less than"
- `>=/2` is "greater than or equal to"
- `=</2` is "less than or equal to"

For "equal to", you could use:

- `=/2` is (roughly) "equal to" (unifiable with)
- `=:=/2` is arithmetic equality
- `=\=/2` is arithmetic inequality

I'm sure you can figure things out.

Alternatively, you could avoid Prolog's comparison operators entirely and simply say

```
gt(X,Y,Z) :- Z is max(X,Y) .
```

or use a *discriminant function* to select the desired value:

```
gt(X,Y,Z) :- D is sign(X-Y) + 1 , nth0(D,[Y,X,X],Z) .
```